# Captcha with Selenium IDE - can I do a 'pause' and ask the 'user' to enter the CAPTCA

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I am using Selenium IDE with my Firefox browser extension, it works pretty well but I have a registration form that uses an CAPTCHA - obviously it is impossible to get the Selenium to 'read' the CAPTCHA (that would make it somewhat useless if it did) - but I need to amend my test to alert the user that they should add the CAPTCA they see on the screen within x seconds.

I have no idea if this is possible - any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible to alert user to enter the Captcha value. Please use below command in Selenium IDE.

```
Command: storeEval
Target: prompt("Enter Captcha Value")
Value: var
```

This prompts you to enter the Captcha value. You can see the Captcha and then enters it. This prompted value is stored in `var`. I then use as entering in Captcha field.

```
Command: type
Target: your captcha location
Value: ${var}
```

There is also another way where you can skip this section if there is no Captcha. Please refer [this link](http://51elliot.blogspot.co.uk/2008/02/selenium-ide-goto.html). You need to add the user extension js file to your Selenium IDE and then use `gotoIf` function. Eg: Refer [my script here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPpgC.jpg). This will only prompt user to enter the Captcha if that element present.